# Check for length of numeric field in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have the following piece of code (which was given to me) to check a 'username' field 10 digits. The field must be exactly 10 digits to continue. It must have no letters or special characters in it -- just numbers. Can someone fix this snippet so that it works right? Currently, it is letting everything pass -- no matter if it's text, numbers, short, long... whatever. Here's the code:

```
function checkUsername() {
  var exp = /^\d{10}$/;
  if (entered.length(exp) >10 && entered.length(exp) <=9) {
    alert("Username is not in the proper format.  You are an idiot.");
    return false;
  }
  return true;
}
```

Comment: It can't be both greater than 10 and less than or equal to 9. You want an "or" (`||`) not an "and" (`&&`). So maybe a little less with the idiot remarks.  :)

Comment: What is `entered`? Where is is declared?

Comment: Uh.  I assume that `entered` is meant to be a global variable holding the username?  Should be passed in as an argument.  In any case, what is `entered.length(regex)` meant to do?  That is gibberish.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The regex test will return either `true` or `false`, it will not return the length of the string.

```
var exp = /^\d{10}$/;
if(exp.test(entered))
{
  // test passed, go through
}
```

And don't call your users idiots, users make mistakes ;) that's to be expected.

Comment: That 'idiots' part was me just having fun with testing. It didn't go into production like that.

Answer (score 0):

hmn its a guess but i think this should work, 
if any character in regex matches with entered(make sure this variable exists) or entered is smaller euqal 9, you´re an idiot

```
function checkUsername() {
  var exp = /[^\d.]/g;

  if (entered.match(exp) || entered.length <=9) {
    alert("Username is not in the proper format.  You are an idiot.");
  return false;
}
  return true;
}
```

Comment: The length check seems redundant now.

Comment: how do you mean? if there is an illegal character inside it will return false anyway, if theres no illegal character inside then it wil only return false if length <= 9

Comment: The regexp can't be true if the string is anything other than 10 digits in length, there's no point in the length check once you've *already* checked the length.

Comment: Nothing seems to be working (meaning: it is allowing any answer through). Help?